# pandas read_csv. How to ignore delimiter before line break

Tags: python, pandas, file

I'm reading a file with numerical values.

`data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep=' ', header=None)`

In the text file, each row end with a space, So pandas wait for a value that is not there and add a "nan" at the end of each row.
For example:

2.343 4.234

is read as: 
[2.343, 4.234, nan]

I can avoid it using `, usecols = [0 1]` but I would prefer a more general solution

Comment: Why don't you clean your csv? There is only so much you can expect if your format is irregular.

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, much better idea to clean the CSV than to have your program deal with all these different things. For the sake of curiosity, what’s your data like, and what are you using it for?

Comment: they are neural network simulations outputs. One row have time and the other the neuron index. Now that you mention I could change my code in C++ to avoid that extra space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in your `sep` argument.

Instead of specifying the separator to be *one* space, you can ask it to use as a separator any number of spaces until it finds the next value. You can do this by using the regular expression `\s+`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='\s+', header=None)
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem. Last trailing space will be recognised as a separator, right?

Comment: It solve it. I don't know why because as @jorijnsmit point it out, the extra space should be consider as a separator. But I checked and the "nan" is not there anymore.

Comment: @jorijnsmit no, it will not be recognized as a separator. What happens is that there is a space and then a new line character or maybe even multiple spaces. The first space is understood as a separator and then the next character is what creates the NaN. If all the white-space characters are identified as a separator, then the interpreter understands that the line is finished and starts reading the next one.

Comment: Aaaah the newline character is recognised as a whitespace character as well! Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep=' ', header=None,
                   index_col=False  # < fixes file with delimiters at the end of each line
)
```

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

> Note: `index_col=False` can be used to force pandas to not use the first
> column as the index, e.g. when you have a malformed file with
> delimiters at the end of each line.

This should work regardless of what type of delimiter you have (e.g., whitespaces, tabs, commas, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying which columns to read using `usecols` will be a cleaner approach or you can drop the column once you have read the data but this comes with an overhead of reading data that you don't need. The generic approach will require you the create a regex parser which will be more time consuming and more messy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the seperator in the csv file to be something else than a space? As this might be the reason why each row ends with a nan. 
If you use:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep=',', header=None)
```

For example, this problem might be solved without having to clean the data.